# Joomla custom component need to create menu

Tags: php, menu, joomla

I am using Joomla 1.5 . I have developed a custom component that's basically a product catalog but with many custom admin options for the product page and categories. I have also created a custom view. In the component, you can create categories and assign them to the products. After every category I add, I need to go to the Products menu in Joomla admin and add new item and assign the custom view, which is the category view. Basically I need some indications about how can I automate this process, I mean add a new category and on save to auto create the menu item, with the selected view, pass category name. Has anyone done this before ? Maybe some article you know about this...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In joomla , for every action there will be a data entry.

On creating category or creating menu.

Just look what all tables are updated on creating category.

Then you can write a function for automation.

When a category is created , call function and update or insert menu tables for a new menu.

You can do it man.

I saw no answers  after 4 hours , thats why am posting something like a pseudo code.